# Replace values in column using a corrections table

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm looking for a solution to replace values within a column using a corrections table i can later add information to.

Here's the idea:

db.products contains data that needs to be `REPLACED`

```
materials | unique_id  |

leather   | a8sd83k2m3 |
leater    | b23k4j244w |
Coton     | 8asdh3k4er |
Plyurethan| h8dhekjnrt |
```

db.corrections

```
id | correct_value | wrong_value1 | wrong_value2 | etc..
1  | Leather       | leather      | leater       | (future miss-spellings)
1  | Cotton        | Coton        | cotonn       | (future miss-spellings)
1  | Polyurethane  | Plyurethan   | Plyurethane  | (future miss-spellings)
1  | Wool          | woool        | wo           | (future miss-spellings)
```

or if maybe faster/better solution:

db.corrections

```
id | correct_value | wrong_value
1  | Leather       | leather,leater,(future miss-spellings)
1  | Cotton        | Coton,cotonn,(future miss-spellings)
1  | Polyurethane  | Plyurethan,Plyurethane,(future miss-spellings)
1  | Wool          | woool,wo,(future miss-spellings)
```

What i am working with now is an `UPDATE` statement with multiple `REPLACE`but these statements are making really long query's and are just a mess, calling a material by using it's id would be much more efficient imho. I.E.:

```
UPDATE db.product SET material = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(material,
```

What would be the right way to go and how would such a query look like? Am i thinking in the right direction (below) or do i need something completely different?

```
    db.corrections AS c
    UPDATE db.product set material = REPLACE (material, searchvalues, replacevalues) 
    WHERE searchval = c.wrong_value1 OR searchval = cwrong_value2;
```

I will be trying more later today so i can't accept an answer sooner than this evening. Looking very much forward to your ideas.

Comment: just add one record for each replacement, so one record with Cotton, Coton and a record for Cotton, cotonn

Comment: What would the query look like to search those records for replacements? Was i on track?

Comment: is the part _cotton_ a column value or part of a column value (e.g. _this shirt is made out of cotton_)?

Comment: It's part of. Which means a value could contain: cotonn, leater, wool. It also contains numbers and special characters but those would have been removed beforehand using a replace.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to join `products` on column value with `corrections`, just join all rows

```
id | correct_value | wrong_value
1  | Leather       | leather
2  | Leather       | leater
3  | Cotton        | Coton
4  | Cotton        | cotonn
5  | Polyurethane  | Plyurethan
6  | Polyurethane  | Plyurethane
7  | Wool          | woool
8  | Wool          | wo

 UPDATE product p, corrections c
 set p.material = REPLACE(p.material, c.wrong_value, c.correct_value);
```

A little bit more safe, because you only want to replace whole words (e.g. *wo* can be part of an other word:

```
UPDATE product p, corrections c
 set p.material = REPLACE(p.material, CONCAT(' ', c.wrong_value, ' '), CONCAT(' ', c.correct_value, ' '));
```

Comment: Ill try this later.  Thank you very much

Comment: I really thought it would run without trouble, but it replaced every value with NULL even when the wrong value isn't present in the corrections list. i can `load data infile` right back so no biggie, just wondering what i'm doing wrong. sidenote, it's searching now for ' wo ' but it would appear in the original list as 'wo,' (without the spaces and sometimes before or after a comma)